# Using the Facebook API to search a name and get their fbID

Tags: facebook, api, search, facebook-fql

I am trying to get the ID of the search result of a string from facebook i.e. search john doe and get his FB ID in return.

Should I use the API? What about Curl?

I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that [FQL](http://ttp://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) does handle requests such as in your example query.